# How to get first text node of a string while containing bold and italic tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. String(s) is dynamic
2. It is originated from onclick event when user clicks anywhere in dom
3. if string(s)'s first part that is:

   "`login<b>user</b>account`"

is enclosed in some element like this :

"`<div>login<b>user</b>account</div>`",

then I can get it with this:

```
alert($(s).find('*').andSelf().not('b,i').not(':empty').first().html());
// result is : login<b>user</b>account
```

**But how can i get the same result in this condition when it is not enclosed in any element .i.e. when it is not enclosed in any element?**

I tried this below code which works fine when first part do not include any `<b></b>` but it only gives **"login"** when it does include these tags.

```
 var s = $.trim('login<b>user</b> account<tbody> <tr> <td class="translated">Lorem ipsum dummy text</td></tr><tr><td class="translated">This is a new paragraph</td></tr><tr><td class="translated"><b>Email</b></td></tr><tr><td><i>This is yet another text</i></td> </tr></tbody>');

    if(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<')) != ''){
       alert(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<')));
    }
```

**Note:**
Suggest a generic solution that is not specific for this above string only. It should work for both the cases when there is bold tags and when there ain't any.

Comment: This should help http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/

Comment: Are you trying to get the user?

Comment: As stated in the question i want this result "// result is : login<b>user</b>account"

Comment: You're not really giving me enough information. I'm guessing that user will actually be replaced with someone's name. It's also possible that account is someone's account number?

Comment: No its just a string which can be anything like "some text with <b>this tag</b> " or "Here is my text with <b> some tags</b> in it"

Answer (score 4):

So it's just a `b` or a `i`, heh?

A recursive function is always the way to go. And this time, it's probably the best way to go.

```
var s = function getEm(elem) {
    var ret = ''

    // TextNode? Great!
    if (elem.nodeType === 3) {
        ret += elem.nodeValue;
    }

    else if (elem.nodeType === 1 &&
        (elem.nodeName === 'B' || elem.nodeName === 'I')) {

        // Element? And it's a B or an I? Get his kids!
        ret += getEm(elem.firstChild);
    }

    // Ain't nobody got time fo' empty stuff.
    if (elem.nextSibling) {
        ret += getEm(elem.nextSibling);
    }

    return ret;
}(elem);
```

Jsfiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/TZKsP/

PS: Parsing HTML with regex or custom tokenizer is bad and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Given the following possible inputs `<div>login<b>user</b>account</div>` and `login<b>user</b>account<div>` he wants `login<b>user</b>account`

Comment: @THEtheChad is right! I want the result with the tags not data in between them

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to retrieve all of the text up to the first element that's not a `<b>` or `<i>`, but this text could be wrapped in an element itself. This is SUPER tricky. I feel like there's a better way to implement whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, but here's a solution that works.

```
function initialText(s){
  var test  = s.match(/(<.+?>)?.*?<(?!(b|\/|i))/);

  var match = test[0];
  var prefixed_element = test[1];

  // if the string was prefixed with an element tag
  // remove it (ie '<div> blah blah blah')
  if(prefixed_element) match = match.slice(prefixed_element.length);

  // remove the matching < and return the string
  return match.slice(0,-1);
}
```

You're lucky I found this problem interesting and challenging because, again, this is ridiculous.

You're welcome ;-)

Comment: i guess you didn't read the question carefully, i said this string is dynamic mean i can get any type of content, even just a text node without any html elements.

Comment: So what you're telling me is that you want the first portion of the string up to an element that is not a <b> or <i>

Comment: exactly ! you got it now :)

Comment: Fortunately I'm not parsing HTML or even attempting to do so. I'm extracting a string, I'm not trying to interpret the tags.

Comment: I am applying it to different conditions, and i will definitely mark it as answer when i am done with it

Comment: @THEtheChad it fails in this condition '<div><tbody> <tr> login <b>user</b> account <td class="translated"> .......

Comment: Correct. My assumption is that there will be, at most, a single element surrounding the desired output. I think what we're wrestling with here is bad requirements, since neither of us have been able to identify the exact problem =P My guess, though, is that the original poster has found their answer and abandoned the topic, so we're all at a loss, except that I think we've all learned a little bit in the process. I like your answer, btw, and you're doing it much safer, just more work to create the desired output (or perceived output, shall I say =P).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<')) != '') {
  alert(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<tbody>')));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Jai but as i said this string is dynamic mean there may be "div" instead of "<tbody>" or anything

Comment: so word `account` is reserved or it might change in other scenarios.

Comment: I want the first portion of the string up to an element that is not a <b> or <i>, and first portion can be anything